# In R 2.14.1, what does wrong sign in 'by' argument mean?

Tags: r

Here is my code

```
slidingwindowplotATGC = function(windowsize, inputseq) 
{

starts = seq(1, length(inputseq)-windowsize, by = windowsize)
n = length(starts)
chunkGs = numeric(n)
chunkAs = numeric(n)
chunkTs = numeric(n)
chunkCs = numeric(n)
for (i in 1:n) { 
    chunk = windowsize[starts[i]:(starts[i]+9999)]
    chunkG = sum("g" == chunk)/length(chunk)
    chunkA = sum("a" == chunk)/length(chunk)
    chunkT = sum("t" == chunk)/length(chunk)
    chunkC = sum("c" == chunk)/length(chunk)
  chunkGs[i] = chunkG
    chunkAs[i] = chunkA
  chunkTs[i] = chunkT
  chunkCs[i] = chunkC
}   
plot(starts,chunkGs,type="b",ylim=c(min(min(chunkAs),min(chunkTs),min(chunkCs),min(chunkGs)),max(max(chunkAs),max(chunkTs),max(chunkCs),max(chunkGs))),col = "red")
points(starts,chunkTs,col = "blue")
points(starts,chunkAs,col = "green")
points(starts,chunkCs)
```

}

Im getting the following error message,

```
Error in seq.default(1, length(inputseq) - windowsize, by = windowsize) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

which I never got before when running codes of this sort, infact I re ran old code that worked perfectly before, except this time Im getting this error message which doesn't seem to make any sense at all! I need help with this before I go completely insane... Maybe Im just bad at this program, but it seems to me that it has a mind of its own... I was also getting an error message before regarding the ylim function, stating that it needed to be a finite value, which is what I was giving it? HELP!!!

Comment: The first problem is that you need `nchar(inputseq)` rather than `length(inputseq)` in the first line ...

Comment: the reason for your `ylim` error message is that everything in your computed base-pair frequency vectors was `NA` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
starts = seq(1, length(inputseq)-windowsize, by = windowsize)
```

to

```
starts = seq(1, nchar(inputseq)-windowsize, by = windowsize)
```

assuming you're using a character vector as inputseq, such as

```
slidingwindowplotATGC(3, "ATAGACGATACGATACCCCGAGGGTAGGTA")
```

ETA: Aside from that difference, there are some very serious issues with how you are using character vectors. For example:

```
 windowsize[starts[i]:(starts[i]+9999)]
```

1. Why does it look like you are selecting from windowsize, which is just an integer of your window size? Were you trying to select from inputseq?
2. Even if you were selecting from inputseq, the way to do that is `substr(inputseq, start, stop)`
3. Where does the `starts[i]+9999` come from? Do you mean `starts[i]+windowsize`?

You should start over and carefully consider what you are trying to do, and learn the right tools to do it within R.

ETA: Here is a proposed rewrite of what you're trying to do (you'll need to install the zoo package first):

```
library(zoo)

slidingwindowplotATGC = function(windowsize, inputseq) 
{
    print(nchar(inputseq)-windowsize)
    s = strsplit(inputseq, "")[[1]]
    starts = seq(1, nchar(inputseq)-windowsize, by = windowsize)
    n = length(starts)
    letters = c("a", "c", "g", "t")
    colors = c("green", "black", "red", "blue")
    counts = t(sapply(letters, function(l) rollapply(s, windowsize, function(x) mean(x == l))))
    plot(counts[1, ], type="l", col=colors[1])
    for (i in 2:4) {
        points(counts[i, ], type="l", col=colors[i])
    }
    print(counts)
}

slidingwindowplotATGC(10, "aagaaaagatcaaagaccagccgccccaccccccagagccccccc")
```

This should get you most of the way there. After that, you're on your own ;-)

Comment: However it didn't work, I am using a very large sequence, and its returning this error Error in seq.default(1, nchar(inputseq) - windowsize, by = windowsize) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (n < 0L) stop("wrong sign in 'by' argument") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: See my comment for a few other issues

Comment: There are a lot of things going on with this code. Could you please post the code you used to call the function?

Comment: you should also take a look at the `rollapply` function in the `zoo` package, and consider `mean(chunk=="g")` rather than `sum(chunk=="g")/length(chunk)`

Comment: Thanks again, sorry Ive been messing around with this code for the best part of 5 hours, the original had inputseq there instead of windowsize, I put it there by accident, but thats easily fixed. The rest of the code is sound I assure you. The by argument problem still stands however???

Comment: slidingwindowplotATGC(10000,ruminisseq). This is what I use to call the function with ruminisseq being a very large sequence, over 2 million characters I believe.

Comment: mean wouldn't work, I need to know how many times "g" occurs in the window Im looking at, but thanks Ben. But none of that matters right now if the code can't get past the second line and the by argument problem.

Comment: user1048244: The rest of the code isn't sound, at least not if you're calling the function with a character vector. Is it possible you're calling it with something else, such as a vector of strings (which is a very different thing). In any case, try my code above.

Comment: Okay thanks for posting that re write, but thats not what I need right now, there are functions there I don't even understand.. as my initial question stated, I am getting this error, which makes no sense. I have run this exact code before without the error, nothing has changed, but it has stopped working. Why?

Comment: @user1048244: You are calling it with a different type of variable (that is, the type of `ruminisseq`). Before you must have been calling it using a vector of individual strings, or something similar (like c("a", "c", "g", "g", "g", "a", "t")). Now you're calling it with a character vector like "acgggat". With a character vector, none of this code works.

Comment: Could you use `dput(ruminisseq)` to get a version of ruminisseq we can reproduce and paste it into the question? (Or possibly a shorter sequence that exhibits the same problematic behavior)

Comment: See my comments above.  This difference in data type explains/gets you past the first line, but it's really hard to understand what sense the first line inside the `for` loop makes/could make. (If I run with the character vector, I get through the loop without errors, but as explained above I end up with all `NA`s in the results.)

Answer (score 4):

A further condensation.  You need to specify `windowsize` (width of the window) and `by` (periodicity of sampling) separately, although I *think* you wanted them the same (i.e. chop the sequence into exclusive chunks) -- if you want a sliding window you could use `by=1`.

The error you're seeing above is most likely occurring because for some reason `windowsize` is greater than `nchar(inputseq)`.

```
slidingwindowplotATGC = function(windowsize, by, inputseq) {
  s = strsplit(inputseq, "")[[1]]
  colors = c("green", "black", "red", "blue")
  counts =  rollapply(factor(s), width=windowsize, by=by,table)
  matplot(counts,type="l", lty=1,col=colors)
  counts
}

itest <- "aagaaaagatcaaagaccagccgccccaccccccagagccccccc"
slidingwindowplotATGC(10, itest)
```

You should also check Bioconductor -- it's extremely likely that there's efficient code in there somewhere for doing this sort of summary.

Comment: if you want to run this with a character vector instead (i.e. pre-split), then just comment out the first line and replace `s` with `inputseq`